# Define proptypes for child's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, children, react-proptypes

I would like to work with props of the children of an element and want to validate those props.

Is it possible to achieve this with `prop-types`?

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {

  return (
      <div>
        {React.Children.map(props.children, (c, i) => {
          // Want to do something with validated c.props.somePropThatNeedValidation (if exists of course)
          // c Is not an element that I wrote so I can't validate it there
          {React.cloneElement(c, {extras})}
        }
        )}
      </div>
  )
}


MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, but you probably shouldn't. :)

Prop-types are meant to define the contract of your component.  Sort of like what static typing does for you (e.g., Typescript).  If you really want to validate the `children` prop you could write a custom validator to do so.  From [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#usage):

```
  // You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
  // object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
  // won't work inside `oneOfType`.
  customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
  },
```

You could do something similar for your children prop (just replace `customProp` with `children` and then validate as necessary.

^^ That being said, I would strongly recommend against doing this unless *absolutely necessary*!  The `children` prop is a well-known and specifically intentioned prop in the React world.  Since prop-types are really just for dev sanity-checking anyway, you would be much better off investing a few minutes to write a solid unit test for your components instead.

The only valid case I can think of for this would be if you are providing a framework and want to provide helpful debugging messages for your consumers.  However, good documentation and examples usually have more legs than a console warning FWIW.

Let me know if I didn't understand your intention.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think you understood me very well. I'm creating a reusable module of components. One of those components is a wrapper for children, and those children could be given a prop that my wrapper should consider on render. (Or maybe this pattern isn't recommended at all? expecting the developer to add props to the children of my wrapper).

Comment: This sounds like an anti-pattern.  A parent shouldn't know things about its children.  A parent may _pass_ things to its children (think HOC).  A parent may _create_ its children.  Any other way is asking for trouble.

Comment: Well.. I understood your approach but since it was kind of anti-pattern anyways, I decided to try and avoid this. Appreciate the response, I'll accept it since it seems like it would have achieve the goal.